# load physical constants into octave

Tags: octave

I was wondering if it is possible to create a file that has all of the common constants that I use, and be able to load them all at once into octave.

Basically every time I use octave, I end up having to open my text file that has the SI values for some physical constants in it, and then copy and paste them into my file. I was wondering if there was a way I could avoid this work, and just type like "load filename" kind of like how I import data, and then all of my constants would be defined in one step?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

Suppose the file that defines the constants is a script called `constants.m`. E.g.:

```
avogadro = 6.02214179e23;
gravity_accel = 9.80665;
light_speed = 299792458;
```

Put this file in a known directory.  For example, I'll put it in a subdirectory of my home directory called `local_octave`.

Edit (or create, if it doesn't exist) the file `.octaverc` in your home directory, and add the line `addpath(<path_to_known_directory>)`, but replace `<path_to_known_directory>` with, well, what it says.  On my computer, I added `addpath("~/local_octave")`.

Now start up octave, and enter `constants` to load the definitions from `constants.m`.  E.g.

```
octave:1> avogadro
error: 'avogadro' undefined near line 1 column 1
octave:1> constants
octave:2> avogadro
avogadro =    6.0221e+23
```

Comment: Good answer. Also remember the user doesn't need add the file `constants.m` to a separate directory. The file can be placed at the current project directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a lot of physical constants, you may be interested in using the [miscellaneous package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/miscellaneous/index.html) which has the [physical_constant](http://octave.sourceforge.net/miscellaneous/function/physical_constant.html) function. At the moment, that function loads the physics constants as per the NIST database.

If find yourself using it many times, you can have in your `.octaverc` file the following:

```
pkg load miscellaneous;
avogadro = physical_constant ("Avogadro constant");
atom_mass = physical_constant ("atomic mass constant");
pkg unload miscellaneous;
```

To get a list of all constants in that function, simply run `physical_constant()`.